# Build SAAS site with Magento as backend

Tags: magento-ce, saas

I have an idea to build SAAS site where clients can have their own independent eCommerce shops. (pretty much like shopify)

Does Magento CE license allow me to use Magento as backend?

Set apart all technical details.

I want to be sure on legal part.

Comment: I would recommend having a lawyer review this. However, I don't see why legally you couldn't just sell it as a charge for maintenance, security and hosting and not for the cart itself.

Comment: any chance to read EULA or contact magento??? iguess if you can run multiple shops from one installation, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Hi !!! Is there a way to make Magento2 CE work as a SaaS ? How do it ?